# Indicator problem

Tags: 12.04, unity, indicator, panel

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Well, I installed System Monitor Indicator to show the internet transfer speed in the top panel. But it shows that indicate kind of in the middle of all the icons. So, when the network up/down, the icons left to the indicator dances between left and right.

Like, Sometimes Upload is 554KB/s and Download is 721KB/s, and sometimes they are 2.1MB/s and 1.3MB/s. So it became kind of annoying.

Is there any way that I can move that to the left so that it can change the network independently?

http://screencloud.net//img/screenshots/e27f771a4600f39e9901de1b5cc2b805.png

http://screencloud.net//img/screenshots/a312e47953ae61001eefa397c71fd651.png

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/indicator-application/ordering-override.keyfile
```

Sample file look like

[image]

Just rearrange the order to your liking, save the file, and reboot your system